# Flutter : Como recuperar uma tela com dados na pilha do Navigator

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation-drawer

Eu estou fazendo um app de vendas, onde eu uso um drawer para movimentar entre as telas usando os comandos do Navigator, e encontrei a seguinte situação

1 - Ao abrir o app ele entra na tela principal que onde é feito a a venda

2 - eu seleciono dois produtos para vender

3 - logo em seguida eu saio da tela de venda que tem os dois produtos e vou para tela de clientes

4 - agora eu preciso voltar para tela de de vendas, e os dois produtos que já haviam sidos selecionados ainda devem estar lá

Certo, nessa parte 4, usando a tecla para voltar no celular ele volta uma tela e vai para esse tela de vendas(com os dois produtos la), mas se eu vou no drawer e seleciona a opção de ir para a tela de vendas, como faço buscar essa tela no começo da pilha em vez de criar uma nova tela de vendas(que vem vazia sem os dois produtos). Quero isso pois, se é somente uma tela na cima na pilha, não tem problema, o usuário aperta para voltar e pronto, mas se tem por exemplo 5 ou  6 telas em cima, é um desgaste grande para o usuário ter que voltar tudo, apertando varias vezes no voltar, para não perde o que já foi feita na tela de venda. Existe algum comando do navigator que faça isso ?  já procurei algumas coisas, mas não encontrei algo que me ajuda-se.

Código do drawer

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return MultiLevelDrawer(
            backgroundColor: Color(0xfff0f3f4),
            rippleColor: Colors.white,
            subMenuBackgroundColor: Color(0xfff0f3f4),
            divisionColor: Colors.grey,
            header: Container(
              height: size.height * 0.25,
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                  Image.asset(
                  "Imagens/ACMIL_CIRCULAR.png",
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Text("Usuario : Iury")
              ],
            )),
            ),
            children: [
            MLMenuItem(
                leading: Icon(Icons.person),
                trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
                content: Text(
                  "Cadastro",
                ),
                subMenuItems: [
                  MLSubmenu(
                      onClick: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ClientePesquisa("",0,"",0)));
                      },
                      submenuContent: Text("Cliente")),
                  MLSubmenu(onClick: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProdutoPesquisa(0,"",0,0,"")));
                  }, 
                  submenuContent: Text("Produto")),
                  MLSubmenu(onClick: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => VendedorPesquisa(0,"",0)));
                  }, 
                  submenuContent: Text("Vendedor")),
                  MLSubmenu(onClick: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CondPGTOPesquisa("","","","")));
                  }, 
                  submenuContent: Text("Cond. de Pagamento")),
                  MLSubmenu(onClick: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FormaPGTOPesquisa(0,"")));
                  }, 
                  submenuContent: Text("Forma de Pagamento")),
                ],
                onClick: () {}),
            MLMenuItem(
              leading: Icon(Icons.local_grocery_store),
              content: Text("Pré-Venda"),
              onClick: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PedidoVenda()));
              },
            ),
            MLMenuItem(
              leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
              content: Text("Configuração"),
              onClick: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Configuracao()));
              }
            )],
          );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o que você está precisando é entender e aplicar Gerenciamento de Instância no seu app. Para isso existem packages que auxiliam como [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get).

Para você conseguir recuperar a mesma instância de um objeto em qualquer tela do app você pode fazer o seguinte usando o GetX.

Vamos dizer que você possui uma classe que possui uma lista de produtos, a qual você precisa adicionar e remover produtos nela e recuperá-la em outras telas do seu app.

```
class CarrinhoController {

List<Produto> produtos = [];

}
```

Aqui registraremos a classe acima como um singleton, para que possamos recuperar a mesma instância sempre posteriormente.

```
void main() {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

// Aqui você registra sua classe, basicamente é um singleton
  Get.put(CarrinhoController());

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Existem duas formas de acesso ao seu singleton:

```
CarrinhoController carrinhoController = Get.find();
```

Você pode adicionar produtos na sua lista:

```
carrinhoController.produtos.add(novoProduto);
// Ou de forma direta, que seria a segunda forma de acesso ao singleton
Get.find<CarrinhoController>().produtos.add(novoProduto);
```

Agora você está em outro tela e precisa recuperar o carrinho, os produtos presentes na lista, você pode fazer:

```
CarrinhoController carrinhoController = Get.find();
print(carrinhoController.products.length); // vai imprimir 2, ja que adicionou 
                                           // dois produtos em um outra tela.
```

Em qualquer lugar que você recupera a instância com Get.find(), você recuperará a mesma, onde estarão suas variáveis, objetos etc...

Dá uma lida sobre esse package GetX, nele explica bem sobre gerenciamento de memória e de estado como usar, coisas que acho que serão essenciais para o seu app e na minha opinião é a forma mais fácil de usar atualmente com o Flutter.

Comment: Muito obrigado, me ajudou muito, vou estudar e implantar em meu código para resolver minha questão

Comment: Se a minha resposta for a correta poderia marcar como a correta?